# What is the shield-like gear the umpires are wearing at the IPL?

Tags: cricket, equipment, officiating

The umpires in this(2016) IPL are wearing a shield like gear on their hands. **What is it called?**

I have read from a couple of articles that it is for deflecting the ball, thus protecting themselves. But, **is it really so? If yes, then what is it called?**

**If No, then what purpose does it serve, and what is it called?**

Picture for reference:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a link?

Comment: @KenGraham Added a picture in the post above, for reference :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, this isn't standard equipment for umpires; only [Bruce Oxenford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Oxenford) is using it at the moment as far as I'm aware. As such, I'm guessing this is a personal piece of equipment that Oxenford is using and as such it doesn't have a formal name, but yes, it's obviously for the umpire to use as protection from the ball.

For what it's worth, this isn't the first time Oxenford has used the "shield" - [he also used it in the Australia vs West Indies World T20 warm up match earlier in 2016](http://www.cricket.com.au/news/umpire-bruce-oxenford-arm-guard-shield-safety-equipment-world-t20-warm-up-australia-west-indies/2016-03-13).